# Javascript show message and hide message onclick on select tage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select box

```
<select id="box1" onchange="turnOff();" onclick="show();">
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<p id="helpMessage"  style="display: none;" >something</p>
```

and js code is

```
function turnOff(){ 
    document.getElementById('helpMessage').style.display = 'none';              
}
function show(){
    document.getElementById('helpMessage').style.display = 'block';
}
```

problem it shows the message onclick, but onchange not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works. It's because that you are attaching both the click and the change handler, it fires at the same time. Your onchange event makes the display to none but at the same time, the click event is also triggered and that's why you are able to see the text.

Edit:

```js
function turnOff(){  
            document.getElementById('helpMessage').style.display = 'none';              
        }
        function show(btn){                
            document.getElementById('helpMessage').style.display = 'block';
          btn.onclick = function(){};
        }
```

```html
<select id="box1" onchange="turnOff();" onclick="show(this);">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>
<p id="helpMessage"  style="display: none;" >something</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, what is solution to overcome this problem !

Comment: What is your point? You didnt explain what do you expect from the code?

Comment: when user click on select box it show a guide message to select a proper option and  when user will select a option and go to other select boxs message should disappear  that is not working .

Comment: Updated my answer. Best option is to remove the onclick handler after first click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="box1"  name="form_select" onchange="turnOff(this)">
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
   </select>

function turnOff(elem){
   if(elem.value == 1)
      document.getElementById('helpMessage').style.display = "none";
   else
      document.getElementById('helpMessage').style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange instead of onChange
It's case sensitive so the capital "C" won't work.

Comment: Thank you ,this  mistake is only in question not in original code .